# Replace value of filed IF MATCH

Tags: shell, awk

I have a file with 3 columns, separated by '\t', looks like:

```
field_tag field_name field_val
```

My goal is to replace `field_val` by `field_val_new`, if `field_tag` equals some value, and `field_name` equals some other value. How can I get this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use just use `awk` since `awk` operates on a file on row/column basis:

```
awk -v  OFS='\t'  '$1 == "some_tag" && $2 == "some_field" {$3 = "field_val_new"} 1' file
```

**PS:** A whitespace including `\t` is the default field separator in `awk`.

Comment: You should specify `OFS="\t"` though

Comment: Thanks, Yes that's important point... Added it now in answer.